# Giving 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax' in format in python 3

Tags: python, format, syntax-error, python-3.7

I am trying to make a function where you put in options and the user picks one.

Python keeps giving me an error message on line 6 and 9 where the format is.

I have python 3.7.4

```
def choice(choices, message):
    print(message)
    print("Do you want to :")
    answer = ""
    for i, x in enumerate(choices):
        print(f"{i}: {x}")
    while answer > len(choices):
        while type(answer) != int: 
            answer = input(f"Enter a number between 1 - {len(choices)}:  ")
            try:
                answer = int(answer)
            except:
                pass

choice(["run", "or hide"], "You are being hunted")
```

Comment: Please provide the full stack for your error please.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using Python 3.7.4?

Answer (score 0):

One error I see in your code is in the line

```
while answer > len(choices):
```

You can not possibly tell whether or not `answer` is greater than the length of `choices` because `answer` is a string and `len(choices)` is an integer. You have also not filled `answer` with any value. To get input from the user in python we can use a function called `input()`. You can replace the following lines:

```
print("Do you want to :")
answer = ""
```

with this line:

```
answer = input("Do you want to: ")
```

This line gets input from the user as a string, then stores it in the variable `answer`. We must then remember to use the `int()` function whenever using the variable `answer`. I will show this later.

The other thing is the while loop. If you want to combine conditions in a while loop, you can not put them as separate loops as this just makes one loop inside of the other loop. You can combine conditions with the words `and` or `or`. So now the loop should look like this:

```
while answer > len(choices) or type(answer) != int: 
    answer = input(f"Enter a number between 1 - {len(choices)}:  ")
    try:
        answer = int(answer)
    except:
        pass
```

But this still is not complete. The problem here is that it is now testing that `answer` is greater than the length of `choices` before we even know if it is an integer. We then must switch around the two conditions.

```
while type(answer) != int or answer > len(choices): 
    answer = input(f"Enter a number between 1 - {len(choices)}:  ")
    try:
        answer = int(answer)
    except:
        pass
```

Now the `try` is unnecessary so we can remove it, and the `answer = int(answer)` is pointless so we remove that as well. We also don't need the number test condition. We end up with the following loop:

```
while answer > len(choices): 
    answer = input(f"Enter a number between 0 - {len(choices) - 1}:  ")
```

The whole code should look something like this:

```
def choice(choices, message):
    print(message)
    for i, x in enumerate(choices):
        print(f"{i}: {x}")
    answer = input("What do you want to do: ")
    while int(answer) > len(choices): 
        answer = input(f"Enter a number between 0 - {len(choices) - 1}:  ")

choice(["run", "or hide"], "You are being hunted")
```

Comment: I am still getting the error at the last quotation mark in the print statement (line 4)